# Python: making a class that return None on any function calls

Tags: python, function, class

I was wondering if it is possible to make a class that, always return None no matter what "methods" are called.

For example,

```
# The following all returns None
Myclass.method1()
Myclass.method2(1, 2, 3)
Myclass.method2(1,2)
```

Basically, I want to implement a class, such that

1. Any non-built-in methods that are not defined by the class are accepted and recognized as valid methods.
2. All of the methods from point 1 will return None

I know that `mock.MagicMock` can give me this result, but it is very slow, so I was wondering if theres a better way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, easy.

```
def return_none(*args, **kwargs):
    """Ignores all arguments and returns None."""
    return None

class MyClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        """Handles lookups of attributes that aren't found through the normal lookup."""
        return return_none
```

Comment: Sweet, exactly what I need. Thanks!